# Data transformations and regression/k-means assumptions

Tags: regression, data-transformation, k-means

I have a set of independent variables and one dependent variable. I am performing regression analysis and k-means with those variables and I am wondering the following:

1) After reading this explanation:

[Can I mix different data transformations in the same model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33193/can-i-mix-different-data-transformations-in-the-same-model)

I am still wondering if it is all right to apply different transformations to different independent variables (for example,. square one var, perform 1/x on the other, etc.) in order to achieve normality. And could you please give a brief explanation or example of WHY is that legitimate or non-legitimate thing to do?

2) If independent variables are transformed, do I have to transform dependent variable as well? My dependent variable is a composite variable which is sum of z-scores of few other variables.

3) Also, do I have to calculate z-scores from that dependent variable, even though it's composed of sum of individual z-scores? In other words, if individual standardised features are summed, is the resulting sum still standardised?

4) Is normality of independent and dependent variable a necessity for:
  a) linear regression
  b) k-means?
I came across different opinions, so I am unsure what to think.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In terms of regression and transformations you might want to review the following question and read the responses .  [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-to-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers/18852#18852) . Hope this helps ....