# If the quadratic term is significant but the linear term is not, we must add the linear term to the model too?

Tags: r, regression, polynomial

I have a linear mixed effect model and I add the quadratic term of *time* in my model  and it was significant and improve the AIC & BIC of the model, but the problem is that the linear term of *time* become non significant.My questions are that

1. Should I add the linear term into the model?
2. If not, how to interpret the coefficient of I(time^2)?
   I have already read the [Does it make sense to add a quadratic term but not the linear term to a model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28730/does-it-make-sense-to-add-a-quadratic-term-but-not-the-linear-term-to-a-model?noredirect=1&lq=1)
    but I don`t understand how to check that the global extremum occurs at x=0 (*time*=0) or not?

Comment: Looks as if this may be a problem about throwing a ball into the air or dropping a ball from a balcony. Too sketchy as it is. Please edit your question to give some details of the situation you're modeling. _Maybe,_ this [Q & A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956231/height-and-velocity-of-ball-thrown-vertically) is relevant. If you're just modeling acceleration and there's no linear term, then the coefficient of $t^2$ might have to do with determining acceleration due to gravity.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your data and seeing some
regression output, it is difficult to say whether *you* should drop the linear term, retaining only the quadratic term. However, there is no reason to deprecate this
idea immediately.

If you have predictor variables $x, x^2,$ and $x^3,$ then you may have co-linearity problems. In the following
extremely simple example Minitab output is as follows:

```
Model Summary

       S     R-sq  R-sq(adj)  R-sq(pred)
0.236001  100.00%    100.00%     100.00%

Coefficients

Term         Coef  SE Coef  T-Value  P-Value      VIF
Constant   12.335    0.510    24.17    0.000
x1         -2.269    0.418    -5.42    0.003   188.59
x2         0.5383   0.0947     5.68    0.002  1016.06
x3        0.36447  0.00625    58.31    0.000   366.71

Regression Equation

y = 12.335 - 2.269 x1 + 0.5383 x2 + 0.36447 x3
```

A matrix plot of all four variables is as follows:

[image]

One may conclude it is best to use only $x^3$ as a
predictor variable:

```
Regression Analysis: y versus x3 

Analysis of Variance

Source      DF   Adj SS   Adj MS    F-Value  P-Value
Regression   1  83744.0  83744.0  278128.45    0.000
  x3         1  83744.0  83744.0  278128.45    0.000
Error        7      2.1      0.3
Total        8  83746.1

Model Summary

       S     R-sq  R-sq(adj)  R-sq(pred)
0.548724  100.00%    100.00%      99.99%

Coefficients

Term          Coef   SE Coef  T-Value  P-Value   VIF
Constant     9.984     0.250    39.90    0.000
x3        0.400237  0.000759   527.38    0.000  1.00

Regression Equation

y = 9.984 + 0.400237 x3
```

In view of these results, it seems difficult to argue with using $x^3$ alone in a linear regression.
So, this is an indication that there are situations in polynomial regression, in which
it makes sense to drop lower powers of the $x_i.$

(Confession: These are fake data generated according to 
$Y_i = 10 + 0.4x_i^3 + e_i,$ where $e_i$ are normal with 0 mean and small variance. The rough idea is that $Y_i$ is the weight of a full cubical container of a certain kind and $x_i$ is the length of one of its sides.)