# Interpretation of interaction and main effect in a mixed model when one is significant and the other is not

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, interaction, interpretation, panel-data

I have repeated (x4) measurements on 90 subjects. The outcome is zero inflated.

The model output gives these estimates:

```
Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)               -2.2151     1.6998   -1.30    0.193 
time                       0.5283     0.2167    2.44    0.015
X                          0.0791     0.3267    0.24    0.811
time:X                    -0.1525     0.0611   -2.49    0.013
Y                          1.0348     0.4488    2.31    0.021
time:Y                    -0.0037     0.0583   -0.06    0.950

Number of observations: total=342, Subject=90
Random effect variance(s):
Group=Subject
            Variance StdDev
(Intercept)    6.302   2.51
Negative binomial dispersion parameter: 3.9265 (std. err.: 0.69723)
Zero-inflation: 0.13169  (std. err.:  0.027756 )
```

`X` and `Y` both vary at the subject-level only, not at the time-level.

As you see, here the main effect of `X` is not significant, while the `time:X` interaction is significant. On the other hand, the main effect of `Y` is significant, while the `time:Y` interaction is not.

I believe that in the case of Y, this means that subjects with higher values of `Y` have higher trajectories of the outcome. Is this correct ?

However, how is the `time:X` interaction to be interpreted ?

Comment: As discussed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4964/is-interaction-possible-between-two-continuous-variables), there are a lot of difficulties and various problems that can arise in interpreting the interaction between two continuous variables.

Comment: Possible dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177337/significant-interaction-but-non-significant-simple-slopes, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4964/is-interaction-possible-between-two-continuous-variables, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62921/how-to-interpret-the-significant-interaction-of-two-non-significant-main-predict